# Make an element fill all the free space in wrap_content-based layout

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I have a vertical layout: 2 text field and a horizontal bar of buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff00ff00"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#ff00ffff"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_comment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#ff00ffff"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:minLines="5" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_send"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_show"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some very long text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the button bar to have `wrap_content` size policy (can't even have them fixed size because this app has different localizations). I also want the text fields to have the same width as the button box. Here's how the above xml looks in designer (Eclipse + ADT) with platform 17 selected (and how I want it to look). Colors are just for easy debugging:

[image]

And here's how it looks on an Android 4.1 tablet:

[image]

This layout is used as a custom layout to a Dialog. No manipulations has been done to the Dialog apart from setting content and title.

Interesting fact: it looks exactly as I want it to (and same as ADT designer shows) on Android 3.1 tablet. But not on 4.1.

How can I achieve the desired layout?

Comment: i don't understand your question (or it is quite simple and just put a layout_weight=1 in your middle button)

Comment: pretty sure he wants the linear layout width to shrink down to the width of the 3 buttons (like it is in the top picture)

Comment: @njzk2: Buttons have `wrap_content`. The dialog itself and both text fields should be as wide as the layout with buttons. As you can see on the last picture, this isn't the case as it is.

Comment: at a glance, everything looks right in your xml. couple suggestions i'd try though, remove the weights from your EditTexts if you are going to use wrap_content for the height, otherwise set the height to 0dp and it will use the weights. also, just out of curiosity, if you move the Buttons to the top, above the EditTexts, does it size properly?

Comment: Have you tried the solution that I posted? As far as I can tell it does exactly what you want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use RelativeLayout to accomplish what you're looking for. Try changing your xml to the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff00ff00"
        android:padding="4dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonbar"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonbar"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#ff00ffff"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonbar"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/buttonbar"
            android:layout_below="@+id/et_email"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#ff00ffff"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:minLines="5" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/et_comment" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_show"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_show"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_show"
                android:text="OK" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_show"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Some very long text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_show"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_show"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_show"
                android:text="Cancel" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `EditText`s have `wrap_content` in your xml, contrary to what I need.

Comment: The layout params are wrap_content but because they are set to align to the button bar edges they will match it's size.

Comment: Thanks, there's progress: this renders the same way on Android 3 and 4, and it's acceptable. But it's not how  I wanted it to look: http://i.piccy.info/i7/d09e06c0c597f0b761e0064b5b679bd0/4-63-440/39513792/1.png

Comment: Actually, there's also another problem with this solution: since the layouts have `match_parent` and not `wrap_content`, they assume the width desired by `Dialog`, which is not enough for buttons. The text is clipped on both left and right buttons (it's actually longer than I specified in the question).

Comment: I've elaborated on your design, made it all `wrap_content`, and now it works. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

This seems silly but it seems to work. Try putting in a nested layout. Change your outer layout width/height to fill parent. Then, inside that make another linear layout with all of your views and such. Give the inner LinearLayout the wrap_content values and that should do it. There's got to be a better way to do it than this but I can't think of it at the moment.

Comment: Works on 3.1, but doesn't work on 4.1: http://i.piccy.info/i7/f00a9d8167d9bece2d372d3a8703adea/4-63-441/4653948/Untitled_2.png